# Accidentally dragged a file

Tags: c++

All,

I tried to .zip a file for an assignment I had which overrode my main.cpp file.  Now the code looks like the following and I was wondering if there was any way to convert it back to .txt or some readable format:

```
œ˙Ì˛����Ä������–��ÖÄ!��������H���__PAGEZERO��������������������������������������������������������»��__TEXT������������������p���������������p�������������������__text����������__TEXT����������‡�����\V������‡���������������Ä������������__stubs���������__TEXT����������<f�����b������<f��������������Ä�����������__stub_helper���__TEXT����������†g�����Ê������†g���������������Ä������������__gcc_except_tab__TEXT����������ài�����L������ài�����������������������������__cstring�������__TEXT����������‘k�����b������‘k�����������������������������__const���������__TEXT����������@n�����ê�������@n�����������������������������__unwind_info���__TEXT����������–n�����‘�������–n�����������������������������__eh_frame������__TEXT����������®o�����X�������®o��������������������������������ÿ��__DATA�����������p�������������p��������������������������__nl_symbol_ptr�__DATA�����������p�������������p����������������;�����������__got�����������__DATA����������p�����Ä�������p����������������=�����������__la_symbol_ptr�__DATA����������êp�����ÿ������êp����������������M�����������__const���������__DATA����������pr�����X������pr�����������������������������__bss�����������__DATA����������»t�����T����������������������������������������H���__LINKEDIT�������Ä������¿�������Ä������P≤��������������������"��Ä0����Ä��(���(Ä����8Ü��X��êä����òë��P��������@ó��é��@≤��p5�����P�������,��,�����B��L��������������������������� ∞��à���������������������� ������/usr/lib/dyld�������������}πıæå+8Ü™Á°¥öïö,$�������
��
�*��������������(��Ä���‡�����������������0��������� ê���/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib����8���������»‰���/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib������&������Ëñ��P���)������8ó�����������∞Á��†J����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������UHâÂHÅÏ��Hãé`��Hã�HâE¯«Ö ˙ˇˇ����HçÖ∏˝ˇˇHâÖ0˙ˇˇHãÖ0˙ˇˇHâ¡HÅ¡®��Hâç8˙ˇˇHãç8˙ˇˇHâç@˙ˇˇHãï@˙ˇˇHã5#`��HÉ∆Hâ2Hã`��HÉ¬HâHã
˜_��Hâ HÉ¬HâHÉ¡@Hâà®��Hâ¡HÉ¡HâÖX˙ˇˇHãµ_��HÉ¬HâïP˙ˇˇHâçH˙ˇˇHãçX˙ˇˇHãïP˙ˇˇHã2Hâ1HãRHã1HãvËHâ1H«A����HãHãRËH—HãïH˙ˇˇHâçh˙ˇˇHâï`˙ˇˇHãçh˙ˇˇHãµ`˙ˇˇHâœHâÖ˘ˇˇHâçË˘ˇˇËŸU��È����HãÖË˘ˇˇH«Äà�������ËB��HãçË˘ˇˇâÅê���Hã_��Hâ÷HÉ∆HãΩ˘ˇˇHâ7HÉ¬@Hâó®��HÉ«ËF��Èh���â—HâÖ(˙ˇˇâç$˙ˇˇÈ,���Hã
¿^��HÉ¡â÷HâÖ(˙ˇˇâµ$˙ˇˇHãÖ˘ˇˇHâ«HâŒËŸT��HãÖ˘ˇˇH®��Hâ«Ë6U��HãÖ(˙ˇˇHâÖ‡˘ˇˇÈ∑��HçÖÄ˚ˇˇHâÖÄ˙ˇˇHãÖÄ˙ˇˇHâ¡HÅ¡†��Hâçà˙ˇˇHãçà˙ˇˇHâçê˙ˇˇHãïê˙ˇˇHã5Y^��HÉ∆Hâ2HãS^��HÉ¬HâHã
5^��Hâ HÉ¬HâHÉ¡@Hâà†��Hâ¡HÉ¡HâÖ®˙ˇˇHãÛ]��HÉ¬Hâï†˙ˇˇHâçò˙ˇˇHãç®˙ˇˇHãï†˙ˇˇHã2Hâ1HãRHã1HãvËHâ1HãHãRËH—Hãïò˙ˇˇHâç∏˙ˇˇHâï∞˙ˇˇHãç∏˙ˇˇHãµ∞˙ˇˇHâœHâÖÿ˘ˇˇHâç–˘ˇˇËT��È����HãÖ–˘ˇˇH«Äà�������ËW@��Hãç–˘ˇˇâÅê���Hãc]��Hâ÷HÉ∆HãΩÿ˘ˇˇHâ7HÉ¬@Hâó†��HÉ«ËND��Èt���â—HâÖx˙ˇˇâçt˙ˇˇÈ,���Hã
]��HÉ¡â÷HâÖx˙ˇˇâµt˙ˇˇHãÖÿ˘ˇˇHâ«HâŒË;S��HãÖÿ˘ˇˇH†��Hâ«ËtS��HãÖx˙ˇˇãçt˙ˇˇHâÖ»˘ˇˇâçƒ˘ˇˇÈï��È����HçΩ∏˝ˇˇHçµÄ˚ˇˇËÌ��âÖ¿˘ˇˇÈ����ãÖ¿˘ˇˇâÖ˙ˇˇHã=G\��Hç5¸W��ËS��HâÖ∏˘ˇˇÈ����ãµ˙ˇˇHãΩ∏˘ˇˇË≥R��HâÖ∞˘ˇˇÈ����HãÖ∞˘ˇˇHâÖ»˙ˇˇHç
```

Right now I tried to change the extension to a .txt to no success.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: The zip operation might changed the encoding of the file.
You need to try to convert it to utf-8. Use a tool like notepad++. Open the file and change the encoding. Then save it.

Comment: This is why we use version control software.

Comment: Learn to use git. It's free and the knowledge will likely be valuable when working later on.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like your compiled binary. You can't practically get the source back from it. If you don't have a backup, you're out of luck.